# Pure-FTPD : How to make anonymous/ftp user allowed to rename and delete file?

Tags: linux, ftp, fedora, pure-ftpd

I have some kind of problem. I'm setting up hobby local ftp server in trusted network. I want to allow anon/ftp user to able to delete and rename file, but after many attempt tinkering with /etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf, yield no result. I'm on Fedora 38, using pure-ftpd version 1.0.51. I also set /var/ftpd to be allowed to written, and the default file is permission is 777 for folder and 666 for generated file. I also try to enable allow anon ftpd write in sebool, and so far no error generated from SELINUX. I also tried to let selinux permissive, and it doesn't raise any error on /var/log/audit/audit.log

This is my pure-ftpd config

```
############################################################
#                                                          #
#             Configuration file for pure-ftpd             #
#                                                          #
############################################################

# If you want to run Pure-FTPd with this configuration
# instead of command-line options, please run the
# following command :
#
# /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd /etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf
#
# Online documentation:
# https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd/doc


# Restrict users to their home directory

ChrootEveryone               yes



# If the previous option is set to "no", members of the following group
# won't be restricted. Others will be. If you don't want chroot()ing anyone,
# just comment out ChrootEveryone and TrustedGID.

# TrustedGID                   100



# Turn on compatibility hacks for broken clients

BrokenClientsCompatibility   no



# Maximum number of simultaneous users

MaxClientsNumber             100



# Run as a background process
# Important: this must be set to 'yes' for the systemd service to work.
Daemonize                    yes



# Maximum number of simultaneous clients with the same IP address

MaxClientsPerIP              16



# If you want to log all client commands, set this to "yes".
# This directive can be specified twice to also log server responses.

VerboseLog                   no



# List dot-files even when the client doesn't send "-a".

DisplayDotFiles              yes



# Disallow authenticated users - Act only as a public FTP server.

AnonymousOnly                yes



# Disallow anonymous connections. Only accept authenticated users.

NoAnonymous                  no



# Syslog facility (auth, authpriv, daemon, ftp, security, user, local*)
# The default facility is "ftp". "none" disables logging.

SyslogFacility               ftp



# Display fortune cookies

# FortunesFile                 /usr/share/fortune/zippy



# Don't resolve host names in log files. Recommended unless you trust
# reverse host names, and don't care about DNS resolution being possibly slow.

DontResolve                  yes



# Maximum idle time in minutes (default = 15 minutes)

MaxIdleTime                  15



# LDAP configuration file (see README.LDAP)

# LDAPConfigFile               @sysconfigdir@/pureftpd-ldap.conf



# MySQL configuration file (see README.MySQL)

# MySQLConfigFile              @sysconfigdir@/pureftpd-mysql.conf


# PostgreSQL configuration file (see README.PGSQL)

# PGSQLConfigFile              @sysconfigdir@/pureftpd-pgsql.conf


# PureDB user database (see README.Virtual-Users)

# PureDB                       @sysconfigdir@/pureftpd.pdb


# Path to pure-authd socket (see README.Authentication-Modules)

# ExtAuth                      /var/run/ftpd.sock



# If you want to enable PAM authentication, uncomment the following line

PAMAuthentication            yes



# If you want simple Unix (/etc/passwd) authentication, uncomment this

# UnixAuthentication           yes



# Please note that LDAPConfigFile, MySQLConfigFile, PAMAuthentication and
# UnixAuthentication can be used specified once, but can be combined
# together. For instance, if you use MySQLConfigFile, then UnixAuthentication,
# the SQL server will be used first. If the SQL authentication fails because the
# user wasn't found, a new attempt will be done using system authentication.
# If the SQL authentication fails because the password didn't match, the
# authentication chain stops here. Authentication methods are chained in
# the order they are given.



# 'ls' recursion limits. The first argument is the maximum number of
# files to be displayed. The second one is the max subdirectories depth.

LimitRecursion               10000 8



# Are anonymous users allowed to create new directories?

AnonymousCanCreateDirs       yes



# If the system load is greater than the given value, anonymous users
# aren't allowed to download.

MaxLoad                      64



# Port range for passive connections - keep it as broad as possible.

# PassivePortRange             30000 50000



# Force an IP address in PASV/EPSV/SPSV replies. - for NAT.
# Symbolic host names are also accepted for gateways with dynamic IP
# addresses.

# ForcePassiveIP               192.168.0.1



# Upload/download ratio for anonymous users.

# AnonymousRatio               1 10



# Upload/download ratio for all users.
# This directive supersedes the previous one.

# UserRatio                    1 10



# Disallow downloads of files owned by the "ftp" system user;
# files that were uploaded but not validated by a local admin.

AntiWarez                    yes



# IP address/port to listen to (default=all IP addresses, port 21).

# Bind                         127.0.0.1,21



# Maximum bandwidth for anonymous users in KB/s

# AnonymousBandwidth           8



# Maximum bandwidth for *all* users (including anonymous) in KB/s
# Use AnonymousBandwidth *or* UserBandwidth, not both.

# UserBandwidth                8



# File creation mask. <umask for files>:<umask for dirs> .
# 177:077 if you feel paranoid.

Umask                        111:011



# Minimum UID for an authenticated user to log in.
# For example, a value of 100 prevents all users whose user id is below
# 100 from logging in. If you want "root" to be able to log in, use 0.

MinUID                       1000


# Allow FXP transfers for authenticated users.

AllowUserFXP                 no



# Allow anonymous FXP for anonymous and non-anonymous users.

AllowAnonymousFXP            no



# Users can't delete/write files starting with a dot ('.')
# even if they own them. But if TrustedGID is enabled, that group
# will exceptionally have access to dot-files.

ProhibitDotFilesWrite        no



# Prohibit *reading* of files starting with a dot (.history, .ssh...)

ProhibitDotFilesRead         no



# Don't overwrite files. When a file whose name already exist is uploaded,
# it gets automatically renamed to file.1, file.2, file.3, ...

AutoRename                   no



# Prevent anonymous users from uploading new files (no = upload is allowed)

AnonymousCantUpload          no



# Only connections to this specific IP address are allowed to be
# non-anonymous. You can use this directive to open several public IPs for
# anonymous FTP, and keep a private firewalled IP for remote administration.
# You can also only allow a non-routable local IP (such as 10.x.x.x) for
# authenticated users, and run a public anon-only FTP server on another IP.

# TrustedIP                    10.1.1.1



# To add the PID to log entries, uncomment the following line.

# LogPID                       yes



# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in a Apache-like format :
# fw.c9x.org - jedi [13/Apr/2017:19:36:39] "GET /ftp/linux.tar.bz2" 200 21809338
# This log file can then be processed by common HTTP traffic analyzers.

AltLog                       clf:/var/log/pureftpd.log



# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in a format optimized
# for statistic reports.

# AltLog                       stats:/var/log/pureftpd.log



# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in the standard W3C
# format (compatible with many HTTP log analyzers)

# AltLog                       w3c:/var/log/pureftpd.log



# Disallow the CHMOD command. Users cannot change perms of their own files.

NoChmod                      no



# Allow users to resume/upload files, but *NOT* to delete them.

KeepAllFiles                 no



# Automatically create home directories if they are missing

CreateHomeDir                yes



# Enable virtual quotas. The first value is the max number of files.
# The second value is the maximum size, in megabytes.
# So 1000:10 limits every user to 1000 files and 10 MB.

# Quota                        1000:10



# If your pure-ftpd has been compiled with standalone support, you can change
# the location of the pid file. The default is /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid

#PIDFile                     /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid



# If your pure-ftpd has been compiled with pure-uploadscript support,
# this will make pure-ftpd write info about new uploads to
# /var/run/pure-ftpd.upload.pipe so pure-uploadscript can read it and
# spawn a script to handle the upload.
# Don't enable this option if you don't actually use pure-uploadscript.

# CallUploadScript             yes



# This option is useful on servers where anonymous upload is
# allowed. When the partition is more that percententage full,
# new uploads are disallowed.

MaxDiskUsage                   49



# Set to 'yes' to prevent users from renaming files.

NoRename                     no



# Be 'customer proof': forbids common customer mistakes such as
# 'chmod 0 public_html', that are valid, but can cause customers to
# unintentionally shoot themselves in the foot.

CustomerProof                yes



# Per-user concurrency limits. Will only work if the FTP server has
# been compiled with --with-peruserlimits.
# Format is: <max sessions per user>:<max anonymous sessions>
# For example, 3:20 means that an authenticated user can have up to 3 active
# sessions, and that up to 20 anonymous sessions are allowed.

# PerUserLimits                3:20



# When a file is uploaded and there was already a previous version of the file
# with the same name, the old file will neither get removed nor truncated.
# The file will be stored under a temporary name and once the upload is
# complete, it will be atomically renamed. For example, when a large PHP
# script is being uploaded, the web server will keep serving the old version and
# later switch to the new one as soon as the full file will have been
# transferred. This option is incompatible with virtual quotas.

# NoTruncate                   yes



# This option accepts three values:
# 0: disable SSL/TLS encryption layer (default).
# 1: accept both cleartext and encrypted sessions.
# 2: refuse connections that don't use the TLS security mechanism,
#    including anonymous sessions.
# Do _not_ uncomment this blindly. Double check that:
# 1) The server has been compiled with TLS support (--with-tls),
# 2) A valid certificate is in place,
# 3) Only compatible clients will log in.

# TLS                          1


# Cipher suite for TLS sessions.
# The default suite is secure and setting this property is usually
# only required to *lower* the security to cope with legacy clients.
# Prefix with -C: in order to require valid client certificates.
# If -C: is used, make sure that clients' public keys are present on
# the server.

# TLSCipherSuite               HIGH



# Certificate file, for TLS
# The certificate itself and the keys can be bundled into the same
# file or split into two files.
# CertFile is for a cert+key bundle, CertFileAndKey for separate files.
# Use only one of these.

# CertFile                     /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
# CertFileAndKey               "/etc/pure-ftpd.pem" "/etc/pure-ftpd.key"



# Unix socket of the external certificate handler, for TLS

# ExtCert                      /var/run/ftpd-certs.sock


# Listen only to IPv4 addresses in standalone mode (ie. disable IPv6)
# By default, both IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled.

# IPV4Only                     yes



# Listen only to IPv6 addresses in standalone mode (i.e. disable IPv4)
# By default, both IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled.
```

The Folder Owner and SELINUX Context :

```
[ben@TP-X220 ftp]$ pwd
/var/ftp
[ben@TP-X220 ftp]$ ls -lahRZ 
.:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 ftp  ftp  system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0       6 2023-06-13 08:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0                194 2023-05-07 08:25 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 1 ftp  ftp  unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0  58 2023-06-13 08:28 sql

./sql:
total 16K
drwxrwxrwx. 1 ftp ftp unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0  58 2023-06-13 08:28 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 ftp ftp system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0       6 2023-06-13 08:02 ..
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 ftp ftp system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0     244 2023-06-13 08:28 coba.py
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 ftp ftp system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0       0 2023-06-13 08:06 coba.txt
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 ftp ftp system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0     12K 2023-06-13 08:08 pure-ftpd.conf
```

This is the semanage boolean -l

```
[ben@TP-X220 ftp]$ getenforce
Permissive
[ben@TP-X220 ftp]$ sudo semanage boolean -l | grep ftp
ftpd_anon_write                (on   ,   on)  Allow ftpd to anon write
ftpd_connect_all_unreserved    (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to connect all unreserved
ftpd_connect_db                (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to connect db
ftpd_full_access               (on   ,   on)  Allow ftpd to full access
ftpd_use_cifs                  (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use cifs
ftpd_use_fusefs                (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use fusefs
ftpd_use_nfs                   (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use nfs
ftpd_use_passive_mode          (on   ,   on)  Allow ftpd to use passive mode
httpd_can_connect_ftp          (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect ftp
httpd_enable_ftp_server        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to enable ftp server
tftp_anon_write                (off  ,  off)  Allow tftp to anon write
tftp_home_dir                  (off  ,  off)  Allow tftp to home dir
```

The output of the ftp client when delete

```
ftp> ls -lah
229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||54365|)
150 Accepted data connection
drwxrwxrwx    1 14         50                 58 Jun 13 08:28 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 0          0                   6 Jun 13 08:02 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 14         50                244 Jun 13 08:28 coba.py
-rw-rw-rw-    1 14         50                  0 Jun 13 08:06 coba.txt
-rw-rw-rw-    1 14         50              11487 Jun 13 08:08 pure-ftpd.conf
226-Options: -a -l 
226 5 matches total
ftp> delete coba.py
550 Anonymous users can not delete files
ftp> cd /
ftp> ls -lah
229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||65372|)
150 Accepted data connection
drwxrwxrwx    1 14         50                 12 Jun 13 09:31 .
drwxrwxrwx    1 14         50                 12 Jun 13 09:31 ..
drwxrwxrwx    1 14         50                  0 Jun 13 09:31 ben
drwxrwxrwx    1 14         50                 58 Jun 13 08:28 sql
226-Options: -a -l 
226 4 matches total
ftp> rm ben
550 Sorry, anonymous users are not allowed to remove directories
ftp> delete ben
550 Anonymous users can not delete files
```

I did check https://superuser.com/a/419683/973279, but as I see I can write and make directory in it, so I don't know why it can't delete, as write permission already there. I already restarted the service after changing the config files. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I'm wondering if [anonymous user delete permission must be enabled during compilation](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ajedisct1%2Fpure-ftpd%20ANON_CAN_DELETE&type=code).  I don't see `ANON_CAN_DELETE` in [Fedora's package build log](https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/pure-ftpd/1.0.51/2.fc38/data/logs/x86_64/build.log).

Comment: @rickhg12hs interesting, so in short, I need to rebuild the package by myself and it's not an error from my config right? I do test vsftpd and anon can write and delete folder, just it can't delete on the parent home folder sadly :/

Comment: I didn't see anything in the config file to control anonymous user deletes, so I searched the github source and then the Fedora build log.  If you want to use `pure-ftpd` and allow anonymous user deletes, it does seem you'll need to build it yourself and/or find another package you could install.  You should know that I don't use any `ftpd` and have little experience with them, so you may be able to find another/better solution.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Well, seems fedora folks has it's own mind regarding it. So could you please write that as the solution/answer? I mean at least it contribute back to society, and you are the one who figure it out. I will label it as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B.:  I don't use any `ftpd`, including `Pure-FTPd` (though it looks quite nice), and this answer is based solely on reviewing source code and build logs.  It's possible that Fedora modified the source code and/or the build logs don't represent/show all the configuration options possible for building `Pure-FTPd`.

[Pure-FTPd is _"designed with security in mind"](https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd/) so it's not surprising that anonymous access operations are restricted by default.  The OP states that the FTP server will be on a *"trusted network"* and presumably with trusted users so relaxing security in this environment may be an acceptable risk.  Command line arguments (see man page or [GitHub README](https://github.com/jedisct1/pure-ftpd/tree/master)) and [configuration file options](https://github.com/jedisct1/pure-ftpd/blob/master/pure-ftpd.conf.in) can allow some anonymous user operations, however, it seems that [anonymous user delete permission can only be enabled at build time](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ajedisct1%2Fpure-ftpd%20ANON_CAN_DELETE&type=code).

Snippets from `pure-ftpd`'s [`src/ftpd.c`](https://github.com/jedisct1/pure-ftpd/blob/10122d9f40f54180c010fb6b42338eea9d3f6ca8/src/ftpd.c#L2599):

```c
...

void dodele(char *name)
{
#ifndef ANON_CAN_DELETE
    if (guest != 0) {
        addreply_noformat(550, MSG_ANON_CANT_DELETE);
        return;
    }
#endif

...

void dormd(char *name)
{
#ifdef QUOTAS
    Quota quota;
#endif

#ifndef ANON_CAN_DELETE
    if (guest != 0) {
        addreply_noformat(550, MSG_ANON_CANT_RMD);
        return;
    }
#endif
...
```

Looking at [Fedora's build log](https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/pure-ftpd/1.0.51/2.fc38/data/logs/x86_64/build.log), there doesn't seem to be any setting for `ANON_CAN_DELETE` that would allow anonymous user delete permission.

The OP may need to build `pure-ftpd` with all the desired permissions enabled or perhaps find another package to install that already has the desired options enabled.

Comment: Thank you! I will use vsftpd, it has ability out of the box from fedora repo to allow root to delete file/folder. I think this is closed with, well.. another way, either build our own package using the flags, or using other ftp server solution. I opt for other ftp server solution. Thank you